# Browser freezes when clearing layers

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I have a map where I need to show some locations based on the year the has selected. There are about 100k locations per year.

Everything works fine during the first load (year 2015). But if the user chooses another year (let's say year 2016), the browser will freeze.

Below is my code. I am callin `markers.clearLayers()` in order to remove the current points (from year 2015) and update the map with the new ones (year 2016).

```
var map = L.map('map', {
  center: latlng,
  zoom: 10,
  layers: [tiles]
});

var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
  chunkedLoading: true
});

fetchLocations(yearSlider.value)

function fetchLocations(year) {
  markers.clearLayers();

  fetch('http://localhost:3003/locations/year/' + year)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        const geo = json[i].geo;
        const coords = geo.coordinates;

        var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(coords[1], coords[0]), {
          title: "abc"
        });
        marker.bindPopup("abc");
        markers.addLayer(marker);
      }

      map.addLayer(markers);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First way** is to reduce the visible markers for just what is on screen. This will increase a lot of performance.

```
var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup(....);

// Remove everything outside the current view (Performance)
markers._getExpandedVisibleBounds = function () {
    return mcg._map.getBounds();
};
```

**Second way** is increasing `maxClusterRadius` will give you less clusters over the map. This also improve *dragging* performance.
Other freezing issue might be creating `L.marker(...)` of 100k locations.

**Editted:**

```js
fetchLocations(yearSlider.value)

var map;

function initMap () {
  // Reset whole map and redraw it.
  if (map) {
    map.off();
    map.remove();
  }
  // Create a new leaflet map
  map = L.map('map', {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 10,
    layers: [tiles]
  });
  return;
}

function fetchLocations(year) {

  initMap();
  
  fetch('http://localhost:3003/locations/year/' + year)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      // Create new marker cluster group
      var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
        chunkedLoading: true
      });
      
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        const geo = json[i].geo;
        const coords = geo.coordinates;

        var marker = L.marker(L.latLng(coords[1], coords[0]), {
          title: "abc"
        });
        marker.bindPopup("abc");
        markers.addLayer(marker);
      }
      // Add individual group to the map
      map.addLayer(markers);
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer my question. I don’t have any performance issues when viewing, zooming,  dragging etc. The problem is when removing the current markers on the map.

Comment: I think `markers.clearLayers()` shouldn't be a problem either. When you create a `L.marker()` inside a for loop. It should be stuck there, this was also my problem too. Or instead of `clearLayers()`, you may try `map.remove(markers);` Hope this may help.

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu You may try this I guess. This will re-initialize a new map.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are *individually* adding Markers to your Cluster Group while the latter is already on map:

```js
function () {
  // On next calls, `markers` is still on map
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    markers.addLayer(marker); // synchronously processes when the group is on map
  }

  map.addLayer(markers); // on first call, `markers` is not yet on map
}
```

You can accumulate your markers in an array within your loop, then once it is full, you use `markers.addLayers(arrayOfMarkers)`

Or remove your `markers` group from map at the beginning of your function, so that it internally accumulates your Markers and batch processes them when it is added on map at the end.

Comment: As you can see, I am calling markers.clearLayers(); at the beginning of the function. Isn't that how I remove the markers?

Comment: It is how you remove the _Markers_ from your `markers` group. Not how you remove the latter from map.

Answer (score 0):

Even though parndepu's solution also works, I managed to solve the problem by simply adding `map.removeLayer(markers);` after `markers.clearLayers();`.